# My jQuery is working in Chrome, but not IE 11

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

Below I have my HTML, CSS, and jQuery. It is supposed to highlight squares inside the box a random color when you hover over them. It works without issue in Chrome, but is not working in IE 11. I am very new to coding and just started HTML, CSS, and Javascript a few weeks ago. Thanks,

```js
//Document Startup
$(document).ready(function(){
  var divs = '#container div'
  var cSize = 960
  var cSizepx = cSize+'px'
  var divNum = 16
  var divSize = cSize/divNum
  var divSizepx = divSize+'px'
  var squares = divNum*divNum
  $('#container').css({'height':cSizepx,'width':cSizepx,'border':"1px solid black"})

  for (var x = 1; x <=squares; x++){
    $('#container').append('<div></div>')
  }
  $(divs).css({'height':divSizepx,'width':divSizepx})


  $(divs).hover(function(){
    var r = Math.floor((Math.random())*256)
    var g = Math.floor((Math.random())*256)
    var b = Math.floor((Math.random())*256)
    var color = 'rgb('+r+','+g+','+b+')'
    if ($(this).css("background-color") === 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)'){
      $(this).css("background-color", color);
    }
  })


  //Document after button press
  $(document).on('click','button',function(){
    $(divs).remove();
    var divNum = prompt("How many squares across would you like?")
    var divSize = cSize/divNum
    var divSizepx = divSize+'px'
    var squares = divNum*divNum
    for (var x = 1; x <=squares; x++){
      $('#container').append('<div></div>')
    }
    $(divs).css({'height':divSizepx,'width':divSizepx, 'display':'inline-block'})

    $(divs).hover(function(){
      var r = Math.floor((Math.random())*256)
      var g = Math.floor((Math.random())*256)
      var b = Math.floor((Math.random())*256)
      var color = 'rgb('+r+','+g+','+b+')'
      var count = parseInt($(this).data('count'), 10) + 1;
      ;

      if ($(this).css("background-color") === 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)'){
        $(this).css("background-color", color);
      }
    })

  })

});
```

```css
#container div{
  float:right;
}

#container{ position:absolute;
  top:0px;
  display:inline-block;
}

#instructions{
  display:inline-block;
  position:absolute;
  top:80px;
  left:980px;
  font-family:cursive;
  width:205px;
  text-align:center;
}

button{
  position:absolute;
  left:980px;
  display:inline-block;
  top:10px;
  font-family:serif;
  font-size:3em;
  width:205px;
  background-color:#0186ea;
  color:white;
  border-radius:10px;
  border-width:0px;
  display:inline-block;
}
button:hover{
  background-color:#0192ea;
  border-radius:10px;
  border-width:0px;
}
button:active{
  background-color:#0186ea;
  border-radius:10px;
  border-width:0px;
}
button:visited{
  background-color:#0186ea;
  border-radius:10px;
  border-width:0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Reset</button>
<div id='instructions'>The button above will clear your space and set a new number of squares per line.</div>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: Thanks, so the squares are not highlighting in IE when you hover over them.

Comment: yo, don't worry about it.. nothing works in IE. Nobody uses it anyways

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE is reporting the background-color property as 'transparent' instead of 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)'. Try using the following clause for your if statement when checking if the background-color is the default color:

```
if ($(this).css("background-color") === 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)' || $(this).css('background-color') === 'transparent'){
  $(this).css("background-color", color);
}
```

Fiddle for proof: http://jsfiddle.net/b64jLfqh/

Comment: Thanks Mark. I guess I cannot upvote yet as I haven't been on here long enough, but I clicked the check! Thanks again.

Comment: All the same - I really appreciate the correct answer mark! Have fun codin', see ya around.